# Can you fuse a low poly mesh and a normal map to make a high poly mesh?

Tags: texture-baking, normals, sculpting, baking, normal-map

Basically I have the low poly mesh and the normal map, but lost the high poly mesh.
So I wanted to know if there is a way of getting the high poly mesh by fusing the two things I have.

Edit: I also have the diffuse, metalness, roughness, tintmask, emissive map.

Comment: A normal map only stores the orientation of points on the surface unlike a displacement map which stores an offset. I'm not aware of any approach that would give you accurate results using just the normal map.